# How to add space following individual row in table Latex

Tags: latex, tabular, spacing

I'm trying to add .2cm of space following an individual row in a table in LaTeX. Earlier "\[.2cm]" worked, but since updating my system, I'm no longer getting any spacing difference. Can anyone explain this? Some example code is provided below.

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\labels[]}llll}
col 1 & col2 & col3 & col4 \\
text & text & text & text \\
text & text & text & text \\[.2cm] 
text & text & text & text \\
text & text & text & text \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me "updating my system", please? What did you do exactly?

Comment: Hi MattAllegro, thanks for responding. I had to change computers and set everything up again, but the code and packages are no different, so I don't understand why this should not be working now. But my experience is quite limited.

Comment: @user9974638: I get a space between the rows where you use ``\\[.2cm]``. Perhaps you have changed `\arraystretch`? Perhaps you're using [`setspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/setspace)?

Comment: I have nothing on \arraystretch. I had been using setspace (I forget why), but even if I comment it out, I get no change. I've pinpointed now that the conflict is with color, colortbl, or xcolor packages. Only if I get rid of them, do I get the spacing. Do you have any idea what to do with this? I need some color package for certain cell-coloring in tables.

Comment: I had the same problem still trying to figure it out.

Comment: A possible answer can be found in: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429272/new-array-sty-and-colortbl-sty-incompatibility